# How to get the name of the property for which the custom deserialization (ReadJson) is invoked?

Tags: json

I have a suitation. I want to do a custom Deserialization for some properties. But i want to handle it in a single convertor class. Dont want to write seperate for each class. 
So is there any way to find the Property Name for which the ReadJson is invoked?

```
// My Class
public class SomeClass
{
    // Private members
    private double m_nValue;
    private string m_strValue;

    // Properties
    [JsonConverter(typeof(AlfhaConverter))]
    public double Value
    {
        get { return m_nValue; }
        set { m_nValue = value; }
    }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(AlfhaConverter))]
    public string StrValue
    {
        get { return m_strValue; }
        set { m_strValue = value; }
    }
}

// JsonConverter
public class PropertyConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        //Here i want to find the property name so that i can perform certain steps based on the property
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }
}
```